# Sum notation in julia?

Tags: sum, julia

I was wondering if anyone knew of a julia equivalent function to a sum using sigma.
For example if I wanted a sum of this sort (unsure of how to show sigma notation, so here is a picture of what I am looking for):

[image]

Both `c` and `x` would be matrices that I would define earlier in the code. Does anyone know how to code this in Julia or whether julia has an equivalent function?
I have used `sum` for more simple vector sums, but I am not sure if that would translate to much larger matrices. Any ideas?

Comment: are `c` and `x` the same size?  use `sum(c.*x)` if i understood you properly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are talking about plain-old-Julia variables

```
c = rand(5,3)
x = rand(5,3)
@show sum(c.*x)
```

But if you are referring to JuMP (based on your previous questions), then use `sum{}`:

```
using JuMP
m = Model()
@variable(m, 0 <= x[i=1:5,j=1:3] <= 1)
c = rand(5,3)
@constraint(m, sum{c[i,j]*x[i,j],i=1:5,j=1:3} <= 10)
```